# Puzzle: Bluetooth data send interval shortened by half after each reconnect

Tags: android, bluetooth, reconnect

I modified the standard Bluetoothchat example to send 4 bytes of data at a time to a bluetooth device every half a second.  It works fine if I start the App fresh.  However, there is a problem if I reconnect as follows:

While Bluetooth is connected, I click the connect button again on the menu and select the same device.  This disconnects the bluetooth (not sure whether this is the right procedure to disconnect).  Then, I connect again by selecting the device, and it will be reconnected.  After reconnection, a very strange problem appears: instead of sending the data every half a second, it will send the data every quarter a second.  If I go through the process again and reconnect, the time interval will become even shorter.  It gets to a point that the bluetooth device on the receiving end can't keep up with the data.  At this point, the only way out is to kill the app and restart again.  Then everything becomes normal, till next time I try to reconnect again.

I have tried different things but nothing appear to fix this.  For example, I made sure the thread sending the data is killed when disconnected so no multiple threads are sending the data.  I was wondering whether the baud rate changed when reconnected, but then why would the baud rate affect the Thread.sleep(500); statement (which is responsible for controlling the half a second data send).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code, the SendClass is created under the MainActivity:

```
class SendClass implements Runnable {
public void run() {
    bytearr[0]=0;bytearr[1]=0;bytearr[2]=0;bytearr[3]=0;
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        if (mChatService==null ||  mChatService.getState()          
                          !=BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        continue;
} else {
          try {
         Thread.sleep(500);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
          }
        mChatService.write(bytearr);

                }
            }//end of run
        }//end of runnable
```

Then under STATE_CONNECTED:

```
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:

                setStatus(getString(R.string.title_connected_to,mConnectedDeviceName));

                    /*
                    if(sendingThread!=null){
                        //sendingThread.stop();
                        sendingThread.interrupt();
                        if(D) Log.i(TAG, "after sendingThread");
                        sendingThread = null;
                    }*/
                    sendingThread = new Thread(new SendClass());
                    sendingThread.start();

                    break;
```

As you can see, I tried to kill the thread before creating a new one but that didn't make any difference.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you're creating multiple threads to do the same thing. Post your code.

Comment: class SendClass implements Runnable {
 public void run() {
       bytearr[0]=0;bytearr[1]=0;bytearr[2]=0;bytearr[3]=0;  while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a thread that never actually stops, even after you create a new thread and assign to the same variable that particular thread wont stop running.
You need to make sure that the thread will stop after it disconnects.
Here is my suggestion

Change your SendClass to:

```
class SendClass implements Runnable {
private boolean stopped = false;
public void setStopped(boolean s){
  this.stopped = s;
}
public void run() {
bytearr[0]=0;bytearr[1]=0;bytearr[2]=0;bytearr[3]=0;
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopped) {
    if (mChatService==null ||  mChatService.getState() !=BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
     continue;
    } else {
         try {
           Thread.sleep(500);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
         }
         mChatService.write(bytearr);

         }
        }//end of run
    }//end of runnable
```

Then when you start your thread keep the reference to the Runnable so you can call the `setStopped(true);` like this

```
SendClass sc = new SendClass();
sendingThread = new Thread(sc);
sendingThread.start();
```

When you disconnect the bluetooth dont forget to call `sc.setStopped(true);` so your thread will finish by not going into the while.